# Search is not working in datatables for dynamic data in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, search, datatables

I am very new to codeigniter, I have two tables in my database then `"ip_companies"` and `"ip_clients"` where I can save companies in `ip_companies table` and I can save number of employees in `ip_clients table` along with Company `id`. So that in one company I can save all the employees in that company.

When I select existing company in form the field details of that company should fill automatically and list of their employees should display under that form. I am using data-tables to display employees table and I am getting data dynamically to the table as I have to get list of employees depending on existing company I selected in the form.

Everything is working fine but searching and pagination are not working when I try to search for name or gmail or department. In `inspect-->network` it is showing what I have searched but table is not changing and not displaying the result, it shows `"processing..."`

Can anyone help me with this. I am posting my files.

my **view** file--> `Form.php` for contacts tables

```html
<div id="clt_dt" style="display:none;">
    <div id="headerbar" >
        <h1 style="margin-top:5px">Contacts List</h1>
        <hr style="height:2px;border:none;color:#333;background-color:#333;" />
        </div>

    <div>
  <table id="mytable" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>S.No</th>
                <th>Contact Name</th>
                <th>Designation</th>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>Phone </th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
      <tbody id="tbody_client">
          </tbody>
    </div>
</div>
```

my `script` in `view` file

```js
function all_cmp(org_id){
    $.post( "<?php echo base_url();?>clients/get_orgID", { org_id: org_id })
         .done(function(data) {
        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
        if(obj[0].org_name!='')
        {
            if(obj[0].org_name !=''){$('#company_id').val(obj[0].org_name);}
            if(obj[0].org_details !=''){$('#org_details').val(obj[0].org_details);}else{$('#org_details').val('');}
            if(obj[0].org_address !=''){$('#org_address').val(obj[0].org_address);}else{$('#org_address').val('');}
            if(obj[0].org_city !=''){$('#org_city').val(obj[0].org_city);}else{$('#org_city').val('');}
            if(obj[0].org_state !=''){$('#org_state').val(obj[0].org_state);}else{$('#org_state').val('');}
            if(obj[0].org_zipcode !=''){$('#org_zipcode').val(obj[0].org_zipcode);}else{$('#org_zipcode').val('');}
            if(obj[0].org_country !=''){$('#org_country').val(obj[0].org_country);}else{$('#org_country').val('');}
            if(obj[0].org_phone !=''){$('#org_phone').val(obj[0].org_phone);}else{$('#org_phone').val('');}
            if(obj[0].org_email !=''){$('#org_email').val(obj[0].org_email);}else{$('#org_email').val('');}
            if(obj[0].org_website !=''){$('#org_website').val(obj[0].org_website);}else{$('#org_website').val('');}
            if(obj[0].org_fax !=''){$('#org_fax').val(obj[0].org_fax);}else{$('#org_fax').val('');} 
            if(obj[0].org_country !=''){$('#org_country').val(obj[0].org_country);}else{$('#org_country').val('');}
           $('#ser_org').hide(); $('#clt_dt').show(); $('#new_cmp').hide();
        } else{ $('#org_details').val('');  $('#org_address').val('');  $('#org_city').val(''); $('#org_state').val(''); $('#org_zipcode').val(''); $('#org_country').val('');
                $('#org_phone').val(''); $('#org_email').val(''); $('#org_website').val(''); $('#org_fax').val('');  $('#org_country').val(''); $('#clt_dt').hide();
            $('#new_cmp').show();  
        }
  }); $('#company_idd').val(org_id);
  
  // Existed Client Display by Company ID
  if(org_id!='')
  {
      $('#mytable').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?php echo base_url();?>clients/get_cmpidd",
            "data": function ( d ) {
                d.cmp_idd = org_id;
            }
        }
        
    } );
    
  }

  
  }
```

my `controller`-->`Clients.php` for getting employees tables

```
public function get_cmpidd()
{
    if(isset($_REQUEST['cmp_idd']))
    {    $cmpid = $_REQUEST['cmp_idd'];
         $cmp = $this->mdl_clients->get_cmp_id($cmpid);
         $draw = intval($this->input->get("draw"));
         $start = intval($this->input->get("start"));
         $length = intval($this->input->get("length"));
         foreach($cmp->result() as $key=>$cmpdt){
              $dsg = $this->db-> query("SELECT * FROM ip_designation where id='".$cmpdt->client_designation."'"); 
              $dname = $dsg->row_array();
              $data[] = array(
              $key+1,
              $cmpdt->client_name,
              $dname['name'],
              $cmpdt->client_department,
              $cmpdt->client_phone,
              $cmpdt->client_email,
              '<a href="'.base_url().'clients/form/'.$cmpdt->company_id.'/'.$cmpdt->client_id.'"><i title="Edit" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
               <a href="'.base_url().'clients/conremove/'.$cmpdt->client_id.'"><i title="Delete" class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>'
           );

      }

      $output = array(
           "draw" => $draw,
             "recordsTotal" => $cmp->num_rows(),
             "recordsFiltered" => $cmp->num_rows(),
             "data" => $data
        );
      echo json_encode($output);
    }
      exit();
      ?><?php  ?> 

         <?php 



}
```

my `modal`-->`Mdl_clients.php` for employees table

```
public function get_cmp_id($id)
{   $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('ip_clients');
    $this->db->where('company_id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;//return $client;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

To make your life easy i will suggest you to use ignited datatable library. This library use jquery datatables, it will help you so solve all search, sorting table problem here is ignited datatable library link

old version

https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables

version work with CI 3

https://github.com/chland/Ignited-Datatables

Jquery Datatables link

https://datatables.net/

enjoy happy coding.

Comment: Thanks For responding ... i will look into that